# Maven 3.5.4 support

Tags: quarkus

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.6.1.Final:dev 
(default-cli) on project thm: 
Detected Maven Version (3.5.4)  is not supported, it must be in [3.6.2,). ->
```

How come Maven support for Version 3.5.4 was dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is explained in details in the commit: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/commit/7364c5b8efaee2253d54a4fe0a712c095c9defb6 .

We were affected by a resolver bug for some of our dependencies and using a more recent Maven was the way to fix it, thus why we enforce it.